# Change the date format read from XML file - vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, datetime-format

That's my problem: I read the date from a xml file in the `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` format. Example: `<Date_Creation>2015-06-10T08:56:44</Date_Creation>`

Then I want to write this date in a new file but only in this format: `06/10/2015` (that is `MM/dd/yyy`, without the time).

What I tried at first it was:

```
Date_Creation = Date.Parse(noeudEnf.InnerText.ToString)
```

But then I get the time and I don't want it. So I tried to do this:

```
Date_Creation = DateTime.ParseExact(Date_Creation, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

I thought the problem was the "-" instead of "/" in the xml file. I replaced them but I got the same. I don't know what's next!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to parse the original to be an instance of the `DateTime` struct. It just holds the date and time **data**, not any **format**:

```
Date_Creation = Date.Parse(noeudEnf.InnerText.ToString)
```

Then you can format it as a string:

```
SomeString = Date_Creation.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: Thank you! That was useful, it succesed.